# This form errors out

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am not that familiar with CakePHP and need to get this form to work. It's an older website and it worked previously.

Whenever the SEND MESSAGE is pressed, it gives the *Your message could not be sent. Please try again later.* message, which means that the error function is called.

Can anyone pinpoint why it wouldn't work, or an easy way to get it to work? Thank you!

contact.ctp snippet:

```
<div class="section position-r align-c-xs-max bg-hearology"  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ContactPage">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 m-b-20 m-t-60">
                <h2>Please use the form below to contact us</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="well well-lg contact-form">
                    <?= $this->Form->create(null, ['url' => '/contact', 'class' => 'af']) ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">
                                    Name</label>
                                 <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">
                                    Email Address</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" required="required" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">
                                    Phone Number</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Enter phone number" required="required" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="subject">
                                    Subject</label>
                                <select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                                    <option value="none" selected="">Choose One:</option>
                                    <option value="appointment">Appointment</option>
                                    <option value="service">Customer Service</option>
                                    <option value="product">Product Support</option>
                                    <option value="suggestions">Suggestions</option>
                                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">
                                    Message</label>
                                <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="9" cols="25" required="required"
                                    placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-hearology btn-white" id="btnContactUs">
                                Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                              <div class="ajax-response"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

main.js snippet:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.af', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $resp = $(this).find(".ajax-response");
        var $btn = $(this).find("button[type=submit]");
        if($btn.hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }
        $btn.addClass('disabled');
        var html = $btn.html();
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            dataType:  'json',
            beforeSerialize: function($form, options) {
                $btn.html('<i class="fa fa-pulse fa-spinner"></i>');
            },
            success: function(resp, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                console.log(resp.data);
                if(resp.data.err) {
                    $btn.html(html);
                    $btn.removeClass('disabled');
                    $resp.html('<label class="label label-danger p-a-5">'+resp.data.msg+'</label>');
                    return;
                }

                if($form.data('rd')) {
                    window.location = $form.data('rd');
                    return;
                }

                $btn.html(html);
                $resp.html('<label class="label label-success p-a-10">Thank you for contacting us!</label><br><label class="label label-success p-b-10">We will be in touch right away.</label>');
            },
            error: function($form) {
                $btn.html(html);
                $btn.removeClass('disabled');
                $resp.html('<label class="label label-danger p-a-10">Your message could not be sent. Please try again later.</label>');
            }
        });
  })
```

EDIT: The AJAX response is:

```
{message: "An Internal Error Has Occurred.", url: "/contact", code: 500}
code: 500
message: "An Internal Error Has Occurred."
url: "/contact"
```

And the console returns

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
VM60:1          POST https://websitename.contact 500
```

The error from the logs are:

```
2022-05-18 10:30:02 Notice: Notice (8): compact() [<a href='http://php.net/function.compact'>function.compact</a>]: Undefined variable: etagMatches in [/home/pm687fsjwplg/additional_domains/websitename.com/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Network/Response.php, line 1229]
Request URL: /contact
Referer URL: https://websitename.com/contact
Client IP: 152.37.111.47
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 146
compact - [internal], line ??
Cake\Network\Response::checkNotModified() - CORE/src/Network/Response.php, line 1229
Cake\Controller\Component\RequestHandlerComponent::beforeRender() - CORE/src/Controller/Component/RequestHandlerComponent.php, line 318
Cake\Event\EventManager::_callListener() - CORE/src/Event/EventManager.php, line 386
Cake\Event\EventManager::dispatch() - CORE/src/Event/EventManager.php, line 356
Cake\Controller\Controller::dispatchEvent() - CORE/src/Event/EventDispatcherTrait.php, line 78
Cake\Controller\Controller::render() - CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 596
Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer::_outputMessage() - CORE/src/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 320
Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer::render() - CORE/src/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 192
Cake\Error\ErrorHandler::_displayException() - CORE/src/Error/ErrorHandler.php, line 144
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleException() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 179
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::wrapAndHandleException() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 163
[main] - [internal], line ??



2022-05-18 10:30:02 Notice: Notice (8): compact() [<a href='http://php.net/function.compact'>function.compact</a>]: Undefined variable: timeMatches in [/home/pm687fsjwplg/additional_domains/websitename.com/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Network/Response.php, line 1229]
Request URL: /contact
Referer URL: https://websitename.com/contact
Client IP: 152.37.111.47
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 146
compact - [internal], line ??
Cake\Network\Response::checkNotModified() - CORE/src/Network/Response.php, line 1229
Cake\Controller\Component\RequestHandlerComponent::beforeRender() - CORE/src/Controller/Component/RequestHandlerComponent.php, line 318
Cake\Event\EventManager::_callListener() - CORE/src/Event/EventManager.php, line 386
Cake\Event\EventManager::dispatch() - CORE/src/Event/EventManager.php, line 356
Cake\Controller\Controller::dispatchEvent() - CORE/src/Event/EventDispatcherTrait.php, line 78
Cake\Controller\Controller::render() - CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 596
Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer::_outputMessage() - CORE/src/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 320
Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer::render() - CORE/src/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php, line 192
Cake\Error\ErrorHandler::_displayException() - CORE/src/Error/ErrorHandler.php, line 144
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleException() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 179
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::wrapAndHandleException() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 163
[main] - [internal], line ??
```

Comment: *"which means that the error function is called"* - This suggests that the server returned an error response.  In your browser's debugging tools, in the network tab, what is the server's response to the AJAX request?  Is there any error information in the response body?  Is there any information in the server-side error logs?  What is the actual error?

Comment: Hi @David, sorry, I should have mentioned that. The error is:

{message: "An Internal Error Has Occurred.", url: "/contact", code: 500}
code: 500
message: "An Internal Error Has Occurred."
url: "/contact"

Comment: Read logs/error.log  and post here.

Comment: @Narcis: That means an error occurred on the server.  Check the server logs, debug the server-side code, etc.

Comment: @David I've added the error logs to the question. Looking around for the error, I found people pinpointing to a mismatch between the PHP version and the CakePHP version, however I'm not sure that this is my problem, since this website is running on PHP version 7.3.32 and cakephp version 3.2.

Comment: @Salines I've added the error logs, thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are using undefined variables into a compact() function. Check the controller that handle that contact.ctp view(it could be PagesController.php I think) and search a line similar to this into the contact method: 
`$this->set(compact('etagMatches', 'timeMatches'));`
You should remove these undefined variables or check the reason why these variables are undefined